# How can I set the path for python3 properly?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/python:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

So /usr/local/bin is in my path.

when I do `which python3'

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

When I then try to create a virtualenv

```
mkvirtualenv py3000 --python=python3

The executable /Users/misdirectedpuffin/python3 (from --python=/Users/misdirectedpuffin/python3) does not exist
```

Virtualenv works when using the default python ie `mkvirtualenv testenv' and when doing 'mkvirtualenv py3000 --python=/usr/local/bin/python3`

It seems to be looking in $HOME for python3. How can I correct this?

** edit **

I can also set `export python3=/usr/local/bin/python3` in `bash_profile`, then call `$python3` with `--python=$python3`, but what I really want is `--python=python3` without the dollar sign.

Comment: I wold guess you're virtualenv is misconfigured. But have you tried `--python=/usr/local/bin/python3`?

Comment: Yes, and it works, but I don't want to have to type that everytime I want to use python 3.

Comment: `virtualenv py3000 --python=/usr/local/bin/python3`. Use the command `virtualenv` instead of `mkvirtualenv`.

Comment: You're `virtualenvwrapper is propably not tied to the correct python. If you'd `pip-3 install virtualenvwrapper` and then use `/usr/local/bin/mkvirtualenv`, there shouldn't be a need for the `--python` option.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/virtualenvwrapper/ihdmGknVsK0 seems the recommended way for now is the explicit path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing `brew doctor`, I was advised the following:

```
Warning: /usr/local/share/python is not needed in PATH.
Formerly homebrew put Python scripts you installed via `pip` or `pip3`
(or `easy_install`) into that directory above but now it can be removed
from your PATH variable.
Python scripts will now install into /usr/local/bin.
You can delete anything, except 'Extras', from the /usr/local/share/python
(and /usr/local/share/python3) dir and install affected Python packages
anew with `pip install --upgrade`.

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
```

After making these changes, I was able to `mkvirtualenv py3000 -p python3`